# Racket: inserting string variables into xexpression attributes

Tags: image, racket

I'm trying to display an IMG tag using response/xexpr

This works:

```
(define (start req)
  (response/xexpr
   '(html (head (title "Racket Heroku App"))
          (body 
            (h1 "Hello World!")
            (div "it works!!!!")
            (img ([src "https://docs.racket-lang.org/pict/pict_196.png"]))))))
```

This does not:

```
(define example-url "https://docs.racket-lang.org/pict/pict_196.png")

(define (start req)
  (response/xexpr
   '(html (head (title "Racket Heroku App"))
          (body 
            (h1 "Hello World!")
            (div "it works!!!!")
            (img ([src example-url]))))))
```

The error shown is the following:

```
response/xexpr: contract violation;
 Not an Xexpr. Expected an attribute value string, given 'a

Context:

'(html
  (head (title "Racket Heroku App"))
  (body
   (h1 "Hello World!")
   (div "it works!!!!")
   (img
    ((src
      'a)))))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're not evaluating the value of the `example-url` variable, you're literally passing `example-url` as the URL. Try this instead:

```
(define example-url "https://docs.racket-lang.org/pict/pict_196.png")

(define (start req)
  (response/xexpr
   `(html (head (title "Racket Heroku App"))
          (body 
            (h1 "Hello World!")
            (div "it works!!!!")
            (img ([src ,example-url]))))))
```

In the above, I'm using [quasiquoting](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html) for evaluating the variable.

Comment: @Arjun did this post solve your question? if so, please don't forget to accept it ;) thanks!